# Pickle Dump to save an object within the class

Tags: python, class, oop, pickle

Let's say I have a class like this:-

```
class MyClass:
  some object here
  some other object here
  def init(self, some parameters):
    do something 
  def some_other_method(self, param):
    something else
  def save(self, path):
    PICKLE DUMP THIS OBJECT
  def load(self, path):
    PICKLE LOAD OBJECT
```

I don't want to pickle load and dump like:

```
obj = MyClass(param)
pickle.dump(obj, mypath)
```

But rather like this:

```
obj.save(mypath)
```

How can I do this within the class definition?

Comment: What do you mean "some object here"?  How are you putting an object in there?

Comment: @BrenBarn may be any attribute of the class (not object of the same class)

Comment: @AdityaJoshi: Just to be clear, `pickle.dump` does not take a string path… it takes a file handle (i.e. `f = open(mypath, 'r')`).  The same for `pickle.load`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass `self` instead of `obj`. In other words:

```
def save(self, file_handler):
    pickle.dump(self, file_handler)
```

---

The `self` points to the instance of that class. So what you basically do is calling `pickle.dump` and passing the instance to it together with the `file_handler` argument.

Comment: `dump` takes a file handle and not a path.  While this code works if `path` is a file handle, it's misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Let's build a class `A`, and try it...

```
>>> class A(object):
...   x = 1
...   def __init__(self, y):
...     self.y = y
...   def showme(self):
...     return self.y + self.x
...   def save(self):
...     return pickle.dump(self)
...   def load(self, pik):
...     self.__dict__.update(pickle.loads(pik).__dict__)
... 
>>> a = A(2)
>>> a.showme()
3
>>> import pickle
>>>         
>>> a_ = a.save()
>>> a.y = 5
>>> a.showme()
6
>>> a.load(a_)
>>> a.y
2
>>> a.showme()
3
>>> b = A(9)
>>> b.load(a_)
>>> b.y
2
>>> b.showme()
3
>>> b.x = 4
>>> b.showme()
6
>>> b_ = b.save()
>>> a.load(b_)
>>> a.x
4
>>> a.y
2
>>> a.showme()
6
>>>
```

However, since you defined the class in `__main__`, if you were to start over the python interpreter session… your pickles would be useless as the class would no longer exist.  That's because python pickles by reference.  However, there's a workaround for that.  If you use `dill`, you can pickle your classes by serializing the class definition as well.  Then classes defined in `__main__` will still be available in a new session.

```
>>> a.showme()
6
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> a.save()
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x01Aq\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\x04loadq\x0bcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x0c(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\rU\xaec\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s \x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x00\x00j\x01\x00t\x02\x00j\x03\x00|\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00j\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00\x01d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x04\x00\x00\x00t\x08\x00\x00\x00__dict__t\x06\x00\x00\x00updatet\x06\x00\x00\x00picklet\x05\x00\x00\x00loads(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selft\x03\x00\x00\x00pik(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x04\x00\x00\x00load\t\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x0e\x85q\x0fRq\x10c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0bNN}q\x11tq\x12Rq\x13U\r__slotnames__q\x14]q\x15U\n__module__q\x16U\x08__main__q\x17U\x06showmeq\x18h\x0c(h\rUuc\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x0e\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x01\x00\x17S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00yt\x01\x00\x00\x00x(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x06\x00\x00\x00showme\x05\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x19\x85q\x1aRq\x1bc__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x18NN}q\x1ctq\x1dRq\x1eU\x01xq\x1fK\x01U\x04saveq h\x0c(h\rU{c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\r\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00j\x01\x00|\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x06\x00\x00\x00picklet\x05\x00\x00\x00dumps(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x04\x00\x00\x00save\x07\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q!\x85q"Rq#c__builtin__\n__main__\nh NN}q$tq%Rq&U\x07__doc__q\'NU\x08__init__q(h\x0c(h\rUuc\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\r\x00\x00\x00|\x01\x00|\x00\x00_\x00\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00y(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selfR\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x08\x00\x00\x00__init__\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q)\x85q*Rq+c__builtin__\n__main__\nh(NN}q,tq-Rq.utq/Rq0)\x81q1}q2(U\x01yq3K\x02h\x1fK\x04ub.'
>>>
```

Then we quit the session, and restart.  Pasting in the string from above.
(*Yes, I could work with a file handle instead, but I'll show that later…*)

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 01:21:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> 
>>> a = '\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x01Aq\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\x04loadq\x0bcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x0c(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\rU\xaec\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s \x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x00\x00j\x01\x00t\x02\x00j\x03\x00|\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00j\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00\x01d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x04\x00\x00\x00t\x08\x00\x00\x00__dict__t\x06\x00\x00\x00updatet\x06\x00\x00\x00picklet\x05\x00\x00\x00loads(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selft\x03\x00\x00\x00pik(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x04\x00\x00\x00load\t\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x0e\x85q\x0fRq\x10c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0bNN}q\x11tq\x12Rq\x13U\r__slotnames__q\x14]q\x15U\n__module__q\x16U\x08__main__q\x17U\x06showmeq\x18h\x0c(h\rUuc\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x0e\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x01\x00\x17S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00yt\x01\x00\x00\x00x(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x06\x00\x00\x00showme\x05\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x19\x85q\x1aRq\x1bc__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x18NN}q\x1ctq\x1dRq\x1eU\x01xq\x1fK\x01U\x04saveq h\x0c(h\rU{c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\r\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00j\x01\x00|\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x06\x00\x00\x00picklet\x05\x00\x00\x00dumps(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x04\x00\x00\x00save\x07\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q!\x85q"Rq#c__builtin__\n__main__\nh NN}q$tq%Rq&U\x07__doc__q\'NU\x08__init__q(h\x0c(h\rUuc\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\r\x00\x00\x00|\x01\x00|\x00\x00_\x00\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00y(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selfR\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x08\x00\x00\x00__init__\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q)\x85q*Rq+c__builtin__\n__main__\nh(NN}q,tq-Rq.utq/Rq0)\x81q1}q2(U\x01yq3K\x02h\x1fK\x04ub.'
>>> 
>>> pickle.loads(a)
<__main__.A object at 0x105691c50>
>>> b = _
>>> 
>>> b.x
4
>>> b.showme()
6
>>> A = b.__class__  
>>> c = A(2)
>>> c.x
1
>>> c.showme()
3
```

Incredibly, the class is rebuilt in `__main__` from within the pickled instance.  Ok, so now, let's go about changing the class methods to use a new `save` and `load` that works with files instead of strings.

```
>>> def save(self, path):
...   with open(path, 'w') as f:        
...     pickle.dump(self, f)
... 
>>> def load(self, path):
...   with open(path, 'r') as f:
...     self.__dict__.update(pickle.load(f).__dict__)
... 
>>> A.save = save
>>> A.load = load
>>> 
>>> c.save('foo')
>>>
```

Then we quit the session and restart.  Since we don't have a version of `A` sitting around, we have to use the `load` method directly from `pickle` (actually, `dill` in this case).

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 01:21:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill as pickle
>>> with open('foo', 'r') as f:
...   a = pickle.load(f)
... 
>>> a 
<__main__.A object at 0x1028c0b10>
>>> a.x
1
>>> a.showme()
3
>>> a.y = 6
>>> a.showme()
7
>>> a.load('foo')
>>> a.y    
2
>>> a.showme()
3
>>>
```

There might be a better, or more specific way, that you would want to load the state of the class instance, rather than updating the `__dict__`.  Doing this won't work in all cases, and it's probably better to customize for your class.  Were it me, however, I would not have `save` and `load` methods in the class, but would use the methods provided by your serializer directly.  You can see above how awkward/redundant it is to use the `load` method from within the class.